# NodeJS Efficient Database Date timeout event

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, events, timeout

I have a huge database table which contains all posted threads. There is also a column DATE and a column blocked.
Each thread should get blocked after 1 week automatically.
The problem is I cannot setup a timer on each thread, since my server might restart sometimes.
So I need to design the solution different.
I also thought about doing frequently a whole database check whereas I keep the last blocked index seperate saved, so I continue from there to check. But maybe there are even more precise and efficient check methods?
What would be good to do here ?

Comment: hmm i guess your server runs on an linux system? you could use linux cron jobs to execute some tasks in an specific time interval

Comment: I kinda want it to be almost precisely after 1 week closed. That means, if you post a thread today your timeout will be in one week. If you would post the next day too also in one week from that day. So the timeout is basically very often occuring. Not statically 1 week periods.

Comment: hmm well witch cronjobs you can set it up to check your database every sec / minute / hour / day / or week how frequently you need it to check.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can setup an cron job to check every hour your database.

```
0 * * * * /usr/local/bin/node /path/to/nodejs/script.js
```

This means: This script gets executed every hour frequently.

With every hour i mean: 1:00, 2:00, 3:00, 4:00, ... and so on.

In `script.js` you can check your database

Comment: Thats a possibility, but it is not efficient. Imagine none posted anything and there it goes a free check. On the other hand people will receive a thread block 1 hour too late.

Comment: @VolkanY well yea, but thats an idea i have got in mind